# How to scan Entity in EJB module

Tags: java, jpa, ear, persistence.xml

I have an ear file with structure below.
[ejb-1.jar] and [ejb-2.jar] is both contain EBJ bean and Entity class.
However, when I try to deploy it to server, JPA does not scan my entity in ejb jar file.
Can any one tell me how to config persistence.xml file?

> ear
>
> -- lib (folder)
>
> -------- log4j.jar (ex)
>
> -- ejb-1.jar
>
> -- ejb-2.jar
>
> -- app.war
>
> -- meta-inf (folder)
>
> -------- persisetence.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the persistence.xml in the META-INF inside each EJB jar file.

Also you can uyse  tag to point to specific jars holding entities.

according to section 8.2 JPA specification:

> Within Java EE environments, an EJB-JAR, WAR, EAR, or application
>   client JAR can define a persistence unit. Any number of persistence
>   units may be defined within these scopes. A persistence unit may be
>   packaged within one or more jar files contained within a WAR or EAR,
>   as a set of classes within an EJB-JAR file or in the WAR classes
>   directory, or as a combination of these as defined below. A
>   persistence unit is defined by a persistence.xml file. The jar file or
>   directory whose META-INF directory contains the persistence.xml file
>   is termed the root of the persistence unit. In Java EE environments,
>   the root of a persistence unit must be one of the following:

- an EJB-JAR file
- the WEB-INF/classes directory of a WAR file[80]
- a jar file in the WEB-INF/lib directory of a WAR file
- a jar file in the EAR library directory
- an application client jar file It is not

  > required that an EJB-JAR or WAR file containing a persistence unit be
  >   packaged in an EAR unless the persistence unit contains persistence
  >   classes in addition to those contained within the EJB-JAR or WAR. See
  >   Section 8.2.1.6.

Comment: Thanks. I'm checking document but do I need to list up all class in persistence.xml?
And is there any problem if I have a [ejb-3.jar] which will use entity of [ejb-2.jar]?

Comment: @QuangDuy  if you want cross references you will have to use <jar-file> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4433341/what-is-the-right-path-to-refer-a-jar-file-in-jpa-persistence-xml-in-a-web-app

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to move persistence.xml into [ejb-persistence.jar].
And then add [ejb-1.jar] and [ejb-2.jar] to persitence by using <jar-file>.
It working rightnow :)